# Django - how to use filter to check if a string field contains a word?

Tags: django, filter

my model order has a text field as: order.remark.

how to filter orders with the remark field containing certain word? e.g. a reference number, a telephone number.

in the order remark field the user can input anything, how to filter orders with remark containing the words "SZFPS/LCB-D2232", for instance. Please be noted that user might type in a lot of information without enter space, i.e. the words are not seperated by space or tab or any sort of delimeters. how to effectively filter the orders?
[image]

Comment: Can your provide some debugging details with what you have tried, as your current question everybody recommends some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well your `Order` model has a field named `remark`, to filter objects containing a certain remark you can use `__contains` for having the case sensitivity or use `__icontains` to ignore the case sensitivity. so you can filter as follow

```
Order.objects.filter(remark__icontains="your searching phrases")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use contains() method for string